# How to implement PSCollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Ive searched for an answer but the other questions didnt help me.
Im trying to implement this collection view into an existing project.
I cant seem to understand what is this block of code?

```
 self.collectionView = [[PSCollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
 self.collectionView.delegate = self; // This is for UIScrollViewDelegate
 self.collectionView.collectionViewDelegate = self;
 self.collectionView.collectionViewDataSource = self;
 self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 self.collectionView.autoresizingMask = ~UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

what is this "self.collectionView" ? do i have to create something in the storyboard ?
i dont know how to use the storyboard, i always use code
please help me guys

Comment: is the deployment target is iOS 5.0 or above?

Comment: yes of course, it is 6.0 and over actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.collectionView seem to be a property

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) PSCollectionView *collectionView;
```

No need to use storyboard or nib.simply create the property and initialise with PSCollectionView and implement the dataSource and delegate methods.

Comment: just another thing when i set delegate and datasource to self it says with yellow, Assigning to id<PsCollectionViewDelegate> from incompatible type "ViewController *const_strong'

Comment: Add PSCollectionViewDataSource and PSCollectionViewDelegate protocols on your .h file

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that `self.collectionView` is a property of type `PSCollectionView`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) PSCollectionView *collectionView;
```

After creating the collection view, you need to put it on the screen.  Assuming that the code is in the view controller's implementation, you need to set the frame, and add as a subview

```
self.collectionView.frame = CGRect( ???, ???, ???, ??? );
[self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
```